# Python 3.x - Merge pandas data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, outer-join, kaggle

I am using Python for Titanic disaster competition on Kaggle. The dataset (df) contains 3 attributes corresponding to each passenger - 'Gender'(1/0), 'Age' and 'Pclass'(1/2/3). I want to obtain median age corresponding to each Gender-Pclass combination.

The end result should be a dataframe as -

```
Gender Class
1      1 
0      2
1      3 
0      1
1      2
0      3
```

Median age will be calculated later

I tried to create the data frame as follows -

```
unique_gender = pd.DataFrame(df.Gender.unique())
unique_class = pd.DataFrame(df.Class.unique())

reqd_df = pd.merge(unique_gender, unique_class, how = 'outer')
```

But the output obtained is -

```
   0
0  3
1  1
2  2
3  0
```

can someone please help me get the desired output?

Comment: you want something like `df.groupby(['gender','class'])['age'].median()`

Answer (score 0):

You want `df.groupby(['gender','class'])['age'].median()`  (per JohnE)